# Unable to use the 'json_extract_path_text' (Redshift) with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, pandasql

I need to run a SQL (Redshift) query, and I am currently working with a jupyter / ipython notebook. I have sqlalchemy-redshift.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine_string = databasepwrd.redshiftconnection()
engine = create_engine(engine_string)
from pandas.io import sql

def run_query(sequalese):
    '''returns a dataframe given a string SQL query'''
    sql_query = text(sequalese)
    df = sql.read_sql(sql_query,engine )
    return df

run_query("""
SELECT deviceid, json_extract_path_text({extra_ctx, 'skip_login'})
FROM table
LIMIT 10""")
```

Where 'extra_ctx' is a column in the redshift table that contains json strings.

I know my query works, because it runs when I query our database directly via SQL Workbench. When I try to run it in my notebook, I receive the error:

```
'ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "extra_ctx"
LINE 1: SELECT user, json_extract_path_text({extra_ctx, 'skip_lo...'
```

<-- And a little ^ points to the 'e' on extra_ctx.

Any ideas on what could be causing the issue? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check how you're calling the [function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) in SQL, the syntax error is spot on. You're supposed to pass a json value *from_json* (for example a column) as first argument and variadic text values as *path_elems*. Your current and only argument is not even valid SQL. In other words, remove the curly braces.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. You're right, apparently I didn't need the { }. I must have misread the docs - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error. { not needed. Does not raise an error with SQL workbench, but does when I run through python.

```
SELECT deviceid, json_extract_path_text(extra_ctx, 'skip_login')
FROM table
LIMIT 10
```

worked fine. Thanks, Ilja